# kuse construct query

Tags: grammar

> しらべるくせがつかない

Please explain the above construct.
I know `くせ` means habit - but it does not seem to fit here.

Comment: "but it does not seem to fit here" Maybe you could first explain why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell me the context, but I can imagine it's like this:

あの男は、分からないことがあるとすぐに人に聞く。彼は自分で調べる癖がつかない。(The man asks other people about what he doesn't know right away. He doesn't make a habit of searching by himself.)

You are right about くせ means habit. The underlying structure is AはBする癖がつく (A makes a habit of doing B).